# Online quiz that can grade a sorted list

Tags: web

I am trying to make an online sorting quiz that works like this:

1. I have an ordered list (for example, presidents)
2. I program the correct order into the quiz software
3. The people who want to play access it online through a URL
4. They are presented with all the options and are asked to sort them (drag and drop, up/down arrows, doesn't really matter)
5. The quiz can instantly show a result based on how many list items are in the correct order.

Features that would be ideal, but not necessary:

- customize font/colours of the list items individually
- ability to detect chunks that are in the correct order but transposed up or down slightly, and give partial credit for that

I have tried various combinations of Google keywords and not found anything suitable. (I suspect it already exists, but I just haven't been able to find it.)